# Using Deferreds to get location and show a map

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to understand the Revealing Module Pattern and jQuery Deferreds with a (what I thought was a) simple example.

What I want to be able to do is call a module to get the user's location and *when and if* that call succeeds show the location on a google map.

Both of these operations by themselves using a bunch of functions and callbacks are no problem for me, but I have attempted to do it in a more 'ravioli' rather than 'spaghetti' kind of way.

What I'm finding is that while the deferred is working perfectly, my module's public properties do not contain the values that I have set during the operation to get the location.

This is my 'geoModule'

```
var geoModule = function () {
    var lat;
    var lng;

    var init = function () {
    return $.Deferred(function (def) {
        getCurrentPositionDeferred({})
        .fail(function () { def.reject(); })
        .done(function (location) {
            lat = location.coords.latitude;
            lng = location.coords.longitude;
            logger.log("Got location : " + lat + " : " + lng);
            def.resolve();
        });
    }).promise();
    };

    var getCurrentPositionDeferred = function(options) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject, options);

    return deferred.promise();
    };

    return { lat: lat, lng: lng, init: init };
}();
```

and this is my 'mapModule'

```
var mapModule = function (mapId) {
    var mapElement = document.getElementById(mapId);
    var map;
    var initMap = function (lat, lng) {
    logger.log("init map: " +lat + " : " + lng);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, myOptions);
    };


    return { initMap: initMap };
}('map');
```

When I bring them together like this:

```
$.when(geoModule.init())
    .done(function () {
        logger.log("location done " + geoModule.lat + " : " + geoModule.lng);
        mapModule.initMap(geoModule.lat, geoModule.lng);
    });
```

the geoModule.lat and geoModule.lng are undefined, even thought the code to set them in geoLocation is running successfully.

I've created a full example at http://jsfiddle.net/faG4J/4/ that shows the logging output.  I'm probably doing something really stupid, so any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those variables which you set are not properties of your module - they're just local variables. You have exported their *values* to the module object, but at a time they weren't set.

However, this is not the way you should do it at all. Don't make a promise for some properties of some object being set, but make a promise for these values.

As modules with only one function seem quite useless to me, I've omitted them here:

```
function getPosition() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
    // pipe the output of the deferred through this logging and transformation function
    return deferred.then(function (location) {
        var lat = location.coords.latitude;
        var lng = location.coords.longitude;
        logger.log("Got location : " + lat + " : " + lng);
        return {lat: lat, lng: lng};
    });
}
```

Then use something like `getPosition.done(createMap)`.

Comment: "Those variables which you set are not properties of your module - they're just local variables. You have exported their values to the module object, but at a time they weren't set." I was just coming back to answer my own question with roughly that, but the clarification of the Deferred stuff is a bonus, thank you! :)